# sqlite3_step(stmt) inside a transaction fails with error 5 without my busy-handler being called

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

*[*sqlite* version 3.28.0 (2019-04-16)]*

I am using *sqlite* in a multi-threaded application.

Sqlite threading-mode is configured for multi-threading (compilation flag: `SQLITE_THREADSAFE=2`).

In accordance to that each thread is using its own database connection.
In addition, since the multiple connections can access the database simultaneously **and in order to avoid the *‘database is locked’* (error 5)** I implement a busy-handler callback and assign it to the connection using `sqlite3_busy_handler()` right after connection creation.

Generally speaking, all is working well, however I did find that in the following scenario my busy-handler is not being called:

1. Code begins transaction (`BEGIN TRANSACTION`),
2. Code working with sqlite-statement (`sqlite3_prepare_v2()`, `sqlite3_bind_xxx()`),
3. Eventually when calling `sqlite3_step()` I receive the **‘database is locked’** (error 5)  **without my busy-handler ever being called**.

I know that in sqlite documentation it says:

> *The presence of a busy handler does not guarantee that it will be invoked when there is lock contention. If SQLite determines that invoking the busy handler could result in a deadlock, it will go ahead and return `SQLITE_BUSY`*

However, my condition is a simple stand-alone application that does not share the database with any other applications. For this reason, I cannot see why would my busy-handler callback not get called.

My question:

Is there a way to configure *sqlite* to always call my busy-handler callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*...after consulting with SQLite Forum...*

**The solution:**

Replace the command `BEGIN TRANSACTION` with `BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION`.

**More**

In *sqlite* there are three types of transactions:

1. Deferred   *(the default)*
2. Immediate,
3. Exclusive

If the transaction-type is not explicitly specified in the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement then the default `DEFERRED` transaction-type is selected.

In the `DEFERRED` transaction-type *sqlite* will not try to acquire any locks until it encounters the first command that requires this lock.

So if the transaction contained one *READ* command and one *WRITE* command, then *sqlite* will do:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION  //  No locks acquired
    SELECT...      //  Try to acquire READ  lock
    INSERT...      //  Try to acquire WRITE lock
```

In multi-threading environment, if the above transaction will be executed simultaniously by two (or more) different threads then a deadlock could occur:

1. Thread-A acquires *READ* lock,
2. Thread-B acquires *READ* lock,
3. Thread-A tries to acquire a *WRITE* lock, which can be acquired only once all *READ* and *WRITE* locks are released,
4. Thread-B tries to acquire a *WRITE* lock...

**This condition is a deadlock**, and as *sqlite* documentation explains: if a potential deadlock is identified then the busy-handler will not get called as it cannot resolve this condition.

The above described how `DEFERRED` transaction work.

In both other cases - `IMMEDIATE` and `EXCLUSIVE` - the *WRITE* lock is acquired **right in the beginning of the transaction**, thus no risk of deadlocks:

```
BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION  //  Try to acquire the WRITE lock
    SELECT...                //  ...no locks activity...
    INSERT...                //  ...no locks activity...
```

Since my code is using *sqlite* in **Multi-Thread** threading mode I had to replace my `BEGIN TRANSACTION` command with `BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION`.

This solved the problem.

Comment: Is there an example of how to add a busy handler? I'm not finding anything online. I'm using Deno fyi which is typescript/javascript.

Comment: @chovy, I am not sure about JavaScript. For C++ I looked at: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_handler.html